# What does this function actually do in ERC1820?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, bytes32, erc, erc1820

I am unable to understand these two functions from the [ERC1820](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1820#specification) contract and its use. What does it actually do under the hood?

Function 1 :

```
 /// @notice Checks whether the hash is a ERC165 interface (ending with 28 zeroes) or not.
/// @param _interfaceHash The hash to check.
/// @return True if '_interfaceHash' is an ERC165 interface (ending with 28 zeroes), false otherwise.
function isERC165Interface(bytes32 _interfaceHash) internal pure returns (bool) {
    return _interfaceHash & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF == 0;
}
```

Function 2 :

```
/// @notice Checks whether a contract implements an ERC165 interface or not without using nor updating the cache.
/// @param _contract Address of the contract to check.
/// @param _interfaceId ERC165 interface to check.
/// @return True if '_contract' implements '_interfaceId', false otherwise.
function implementsERC165InterfaceNoCache(address _contract, bytes4 _interfaceId) public view returns (bool) {
    uint256 success;
    uint256 result;

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, ERC165ID);
    if (success == 0 || result == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, INVALID_ID);
    if (success == 0 || result != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, _interfaceId);
    if (success == 1 && result == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```